# How to solve the central admin BCS Credential issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

[image]

In central admin, if i set credential for BCS it display this error.

Comment: did you play around with master page or edit the welcome page?

Comment: no i didnt touch welcome page.i added connection string in master page,thats all i did.